# Estoy estilizando formulario con css y no se porque me ocurre esto

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo un formulario pero no se porque me queda un espacio en blanco arriba, como podría solucionarlo. Este es mi código html.

```css
body {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
input {
    margin: 15px;
}
.boton {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
form {
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: -20px;
}
h2 {
    background-color: #46cd63;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="">
            <h2>Crear carpetas en Google Drive</h2>
            <label for="">Nombre de la carpeta a compartir Read/write</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id=""> <br>
            <label for="">Nombre de la carpeta a compartir Read/write</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id=""> <br>
            <input class="boton" type="button" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Como podría hacer para quitar el espacio en blanco que está encima de la etiqueta h2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añadiendo `margin-top: 0;` al `h2`, ten en cuenta que las etiquetas `h` tienen un margen vertical por defecto útil a separar los títulos del resto del cuerpo, la `h` esta por heading (título).

Este sería el codigo:

```css
body {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
input {
    margin: 15px;
}
.boton {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
form {
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: -20px;
}
h2 {
    background-color: #46cd63;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
;
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="">
            <h2>Crear carpetas en Google Drive</h2>
            <label for="">Nombre de la carpeta a compartir Read/write</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id=""> <br>
            <label for="">Nombre de la carpeta a compartir Read/write</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id=""> <br>
            <input class="boton" type="button" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido.